# Doctrine Dynamic Relationship does not work

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need a way to create relations on the fly, and I choose the Event of the doctrine that is launched when load the class meta data, loadClassMetadata()

```
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

    $this->em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    if ($metadata->getName() != 'AppBundle\Entity\NewsNews') {
        return;
    }
    $attachmentsMetadata = $this->getAttachmentsClassMetadata();

    $attachmentsMetadata->mapManyToOne(
        [
            "targetEntity" => $metadata->getName(),
            "fieldName"    => "newsNews",
            'joinColumns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'foreign_key',
                    'referencedColumnName' => 'id'
                )
            ),
            "inversedBy" => "attachments"
        ]
    );
    $attachmentsMetadata->initializeReflection();

    $metadata->mapOneToMany(
        [
            "targetEntity" => $attachmentsMetadata->getName(),
            "fieldName"    => "attachments",
            'joinColumns' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'id',
                    'referencedColumnName' => 'foreign_key'
                )
            ),
            "mappedBy" => "newsNews"
        ]
    );
}
```

Ok, worked but the problem is when the doctrine will set the data for this relations he throw this exception "**Notice: Undefined index: newsNews**"
I've checked the class when the doctrine will attach this data and the newsNews field is missing in the reflection properties.
I don't know if I forget some part of this process xD

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why would you need this and furthermore what's the purpose of such "dynamic" code?

Comment: I wanted to create own application relationships automatically, without my having to change the bundle.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings are not meant to be changed at runtime, your proposed solution is more of a hack to Doctrine and, while it could work, it will probably lead you to more hacks along the way.

If your restriction is that you don't want to modify the `Attachment` mapping, you can do a **one-to-many association with joined table**.

This way, you only need to map the inverse side of the one-to-many. But, you'll only be able to navigate it that way.

Documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table